# how do I prevent VS2010 from auto-adding new SharePoint modules to a random feature

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-feature

I have a rather large SharePoint project in Visual Studio 2010 with a number of features in it. Every time I add a new module or empty element to the project, Visual Studio seems to randomly choose a feature to add it to, which I totally hate.

Luckily my project is connected to source control, so I can easily see which feature was modified by checking to see which one got auto-checked out for me. If it were not source control backed, I would literally have to open up each feature and examine it to see where it went.

I've searched but cannot find any setting to turn this "helpful" feature of Visual Studio off. How can I make it stop? I want to be able to add it to a feature only when I'm good and ready to...

Comment: This extension is designed to prevent that behavior http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9c7c4a73-3558-4712-a65c-badf070e4abc

Answer (score 0):

I might just be superstitious, but I've had good luck when the feature I'm targeting (and only that feature) is open in the current documents. When I do that, I can't think of a time where a new item has been added to a different feature.

Comment: that's interesting, maybe that's why it always seems so random for me.. i'll give that a shot, although i would still prefer to turn the behavior off altogether.

Comment: nope, i just tried it. had one feature open and nothing else.. added a module, and it went to some other random feature. :(